# Последние записи wordpress на отдельной странице

Tags: php, wordpress

Как вывести последние записи на отдельной странице в wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

Этот код выведет 5 последних постов

```
    <?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );

foreach( $lastposts as $post ){
    setup_postdata($post); // устанавливаем данные
    ?>

    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php
}
wp_reset_postdata(); // сброс
?>
```

Полная документация по get_posts(); Здесь http://wp-kama.ru/function/get_posts